# Order columns in R in ASCII order

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, columnsorting

I would like to order the column names I have in ASCII order, which means that **all LARGE letters come before small letters**.

For example, I have made this code:

```
test_ordered <- test[ , sort(names(test))]
```

Which indeed sorts the column names by name, like this:

```
A B d F g H
```

However, what I want to achieve here is the following:

```
A B F H d g
```

Which is the standard way `sorted()` from Python works:

```
df_curr = df_curr[sorted(df_curr)]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `withr::with_collate("C", sort(test))`. Or `stringr::str_sort(test, locale = "C")`

Comment: It says undefined columns selected - when putting sort(names(test)) that does the trick but I only recover the column names, not the whole dataframe

Comment: > test_ordered <- withr::with_collate("C", sort(test))
Error in `[.data.frame`(x, order(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing)) : 
  undefined columns selected

Comment: Figured that one out: test_ordered <- test[withr::with_collate("C", sort(names(test)))]

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Focused on sorting a character vector forgetting it needed to the column names.

Comment: To be clear: `sort()` and `order()` collation depends on locale attributes, which are controlled by `Sys.setlocale()`. If you perform any kind of string comparison in R without controlling locale explicitly your code will potentially have reproducibility problems. withr, etc. control locale by evaluating expressions in a new environment where global properties like locale are different